# Hadoop - Elasticsearch - Spark version compatibility

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, elasticsearch

Before, I had Kibana/Elasticsearch in version 5.3.0.
In my java project, the dependencies were :

- hbase-client/server… 1.2.1
- hadoop-hdfs/common…  2.5.1
- elasticsearch-hadoop 5.3.0
- Spark (spark-core_2.11)  1.3.0

The whole was functional.

I want to update Kibana / ES in version 6.3.1.
Which versions of Hadoop / spark are compatible? I can not find a compatibility matrix ...

- hbase-client/server… ?
- hadoop-hdfs/common…  ?
- elasticsearch-hadoop 6.3.1 ?
- Spark (spark-core_2.11)  1.6.1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> elasticsearch-hadoop binary is suitable for Hadoop 2.x (also known as YARN) environments. Support for Hadoop 1.x environments are deprecated in 5.5 and will no longer be tested against in 6.0.

Spark is built against Hadoop 2.6+, so you should upgrade Hadoop as the least common denominator here. You should definitely be using Spark 2.x as well for numerous reasons such as bug fixes, and AFAIK, the RDD API is in "maintenance mode" and DataFrames are recommended

HBase documentation has its own compatibility charts, but is unrelated to Elasticsearch. The latest stable Hbase is 1.4.3

1.2.1 looks like a **Hive** version number, though, and that version works fine, but again, not the latest stable 1.x release

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing tests with : hadoop 2.5.1 ; spark-core 2.3.0 ; elasticsearch-hadoop 6.3.1 ; scala-library 2.11.8.  I get : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;"

Comment: Are you sure you're using Scala 2.11? I've seen a similar error with 2.12

Comment: If you search that error elsewhere, it mentions you have classes using Scala 2.10... And in the Spark download page, *Starting version 2.0, Spark is built with Scala 2.11 by default. Scala 2.10 users should download the Spark source package and build with Scala 2.10 support.*

Comment: Yes, all dependencies use scala 2.11. I don't have any scala 2.10 dependency.